# I converted my htaccess to nginx, can someone confirm?

Tags: .htaccess, nginx

I'm looking to translate an `htaccess` to `nginx` but I'm not comfortable with it.

I used https://winginx.com/en/htaccess to do it but can someone look and confirm if this config is correct?

My htaccess :

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/laabs/web/

ServerName maarchrm

Options -Indexes
Options FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/public [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /http.php [QSA,L]
```

winginx translation :

```
server_name maarchrm;

root /var/www/laabs/web/;

autoindex off;

location ~ ^(.*)$ { }

autoindex off;

location /public {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /http.php break;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: That actually is what your test suite is for...